# Employee Directory

Tags: 2010

I have developed a Employee Directory and got this javascript for criteria search. But I want to fetch all employees first and then apply criteria.

How do I set the value of "Fixed Query" of People Search Core Result webpart using javascript, when I press the search button without giving any criteria.

```
<script language="javascript">

    //function for enter on keyboard and apostrophes in search strings
    function txtWildPeopleFinder_KeyDown(e)
    {
        if (e.keyCode == 13 || e.keyCode==10)
        {
            e.returnValue=false;
            DoWildPeopleSearch();
            return false;
        }
        else
            return true;
    }

    function escapestr(str)
    {
        return str.replace("'","%22");
    }

    //staff search
    function DoWildPeopleSearch()
    {
        var firstname = escapestr(document.all["firstname"].value);
        var lastname = escapestr(document.all["lastname"].value);
        var url;

        //search on last name onnly (first name is empty)
        if(firstname == "")
        {
            url = "BankDirectory.aspx?k=LastName%3A" + lastname;
            window.location=url;
            return;
        }

        //search on first name only (last name is empty)
        if(lastname == "")
        {
            url = "BankDirectory.aspx?k=FirstName%3A" + firstname;
            window.location=url;
            return;
        }

        //search on first and last
        url = "BankDirectory.aspx?k=lastname%3A" + lastname + "%20FirstName%3A" + firstname;
        window.location=url;
        return;
    }
 </script>

 <table width="100%" id="StaffSearchTable" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="80" nowrap="nowrap">First Name:</td>
            <td width="100%"><input name="firstname" id="firstname" onkeydown="txtWildPeopleFinder_KeyDown(event)" type="text" size="25" maxlength="55"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="80" nowrap="nowrap">Last Name:</td>  
            <td><input name="lastname" id="lastname" onkeydown="txtWildPeopleFinder_KeyDown(event)" type="text" size="25"     maxlength="55"/> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input onclick="DoWildPeopleSearch()" type="button" value="Search"/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>   
<p>
    Enter all or part of a name
    <br/>e.g. A will find all names beginning with A
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to edit the CoreSearchResults web part properties and use the "Append Text to Query", see here http://www.sharepointconfig.com/2011/05/how-to-create-a-simple-sharepoint-2010-people-directory/

This shall automatically trigger a query and still allow you to add your own Keywords.